# Unity desktop loads ONLY after rebooting and updating every single time

Tags: boot, drivers, unity, nvidia

I'm new to Ubuntu to start things off (v. 16.04 LTS)

Like the title says itself, to explain more - whenever I boot Ubuntu for the first time in a day, after login, the screen starts *flickering* black/background wallpaper unable to load into Unity desktop.
I enter the terminal and do a simple update by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Simple. And reboot. After this, every single time, I get into the default desktop and Unity works normally.

SO - Any ideas for permament fix? (so I don't have to do this everytime I try to boot the system)

*mention:* I've been having nvidia drivers problems in the past, and probably still do (enabled the proprietary nvidia driver, mine v304.135, but somehow i ended up not loading into the login screen at all and got stuck in terminal), since I'm using the nouveau display driver at the moment (which seems to be working fine after I get into Unity).

Comment: Have you already tried to install latest nvidia drivers (v375)?

Comment: Not quite yet.. wanted to wait for the response on the post and thoughts/explanations why does this thing keep happening to me (especially after the update it works fine?).

Comment: is there any reason why you want the nvidia drivers? do you have a very high resolution or do you want to play games? do you have GPU-centric programs?

Comment: I don't need nvidia drivers in ubuntu if possible, just want to fix my issue.